# Query Table with Multiple Currencies Based on Date Range

Tags: arrays, datetime, google-sheets, string-formatting, google-query-language

I am trying to create a query based on a date range, that will display multiple currencies and re-label a column header. [Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SW__sr7ifG7u24XmbrYE6kV996RMHxCQVUYLQegRvgc/edit#gid=0) is the sample dataset I'm working with.

I'm able to successfully query the table using `=ArrayFormula(QUERY({A4:B14,TO_TEXT(C4:C14),D4:D14},"Select *"))`.  (without TO_TEXT, any currency that is not $USD does not display in the output)

However, if I try to select a column instead of `Select *` AND/OR if I add criteria such as a date range, it creates a #VALUE error.

Here is the full formula that is not working:

```
=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA({A4:B,TO_TEXT(C4:C),D4:D}),"select A, B, C where D >= date '"&TEXT(A$2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and D <= date '"&TEXT(B$2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' Label C 'Cost'")
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA({A4:B,TO_TEXT(C4:C),D4:D}),
 "select Col1, Col2, Col3 
  where Col4 >= date '"&TEXT(A$2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
    and Col4 <= date '"&TEXT(B$2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'")
```

[image]

when range is constructed you need to use `Col` reference in your query